# Device cannot access Internal Storage without elevated rights

Tags: root-access, internal-storage, permissions, magisk

After my NANDroid restore didn't work as expected, flashed a clean ROM + Magisk.

When booted to system, internal storage is not accessible (regular File Manager, MTP, adb shell, MiXplorer's Internal Storage).

But it is accessible via elevated rights (TWRP File Manager, MTP when in recovery mode, su in adb shell, Root option in MiXplorer).

Permission while in recovery and booted to system are respectively:

> drwxrwxrwx   2 system   system    4096 1970-01-01 18:21 sdcard
>
> lrw-r--r--   1 root   root      21 2009-01-01 05:30 sdcard ->
> /storage/self/primary

--> Tried `chmod -R 777 sdcard` with no luck. As it is a symlink, did chmod directly to `/storage/self/primary` and `/storage/emulated/0` but it doesn't have an effect.

--> Tried from scratch, wiping and formatting every partition and entire Internal Storage, tried older known working ROMs. Still the same.

Surely, it's a permissions issue. What am I missing?

Comment: try maybe `chmod 777 /data/media/0` or `chmod -R /data/media/0`

Comment: Nothing changes. However, `chmod -R 777 sdcard` when in recovery (root) now resulted in `drwxrwx---   4 media_rw media_rw    4096 2022-06-06 14:44 sdcard`

Comment: has it been solved now?

Comment: Sorry if I wasn't clear. It's the same as only with su access internal storage is accessible.

Comment: Oh sorry. I didnt get that part. Hope you will get a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After being stumbled for days, found a very simple solution. This will need root privileges.

From an ADB shell or terminal emulator in phone:

```
su
restorecon -v -R /data/media
```

This will make Internal Storage mounted at `/data/media` readable again, without any data loss.

Source: [XDA](https://forum.xda-developers.com/t/guide-internal-sdcard-not-writable-fix.2684384/post-51152906), as referred by [this post](https://androidforums.com/threads/internal-phone-storage-becomes-read-only.347685/#post-6939013):

Tip: Using different search engines with same keyword helps to find additional threads/ articles.